# During WPF Window resize; how to delay the resizing of its contents?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I have a WPF window which contains some rich graphical controls, laid out in such a way as to fill the entire window (i.e. `HorizontalAlignment.Stretch`).  The standard behavior when a user resizes the parent window is for the controls to expand/contract in real time with the window.

I'd like to modify this behavior slightly, to do the following:

- When a user begins to resize the window, the content 'freezes' in place and fades out (`Opacity="0"`)
- When a user stops resizing (say, after 250ms of inactivity), the controls 'fade in' at the new size.

Essentially, I don't want to show the transitional period where the controls are actually growing or shrinking.  Just have them disappear, them reappear with the proper size.

Is there a way to do this in WPF using event triggers and standard fade animations?  Or is it going to be a much more complex solution which requires my controls be bound to some custom 'dimensions' manager?

Comment: There's no `Window.IsResizing`, but you could easily implement it yourself using a DependencyProperty and a couple of events to toggle it true/false. Then you could use `Trigger`s to start animations and the like.